# Is the View class synonymous to View component in MVC?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, view, draw, ondraw

So, I have searched the net to try and understand the difference between View.draw() and View.onDraw() but nobody seems to know and frankly I don't even know if I am approaching the problem correctly. All help is welcome.

The problem is :

1. I have a canvas Object, and it is NOT part of the custom View class
2. The canvas Object in question is part of a Data Access Object(DAO)
3. I want the View to draw the canvas of DAO when onDraw() is called.

Now, the problem seems to be that:

1. I should NOT call the onDraw() manually
2. Even if I do call it, onDraw() takes a parameter which is essentially a output parameter and therefore no point to pass the DAO.canavas to it.

Question is, How do I pass my DAO.canvas to the View so that onDraw() can access it and copy to it's output parameter which is a canvas itself?
Also, if it is possible, I would like to keep model and view separate.
If anybody knows, I would like to know if View.Draw() method's parameter is also "output" type?

Comment: draw is similar to onDraw, it draws some common View related stuff (background, fade edges, scrollbars) and calls onDraw to draw specific things

Comment: @pskink : I got that much from the documentation, the doubt I have is, do I draw stuff on the Canvas parameter of the Draw function or I can pass a pre-built Canvas as a parameter to Draw and it will render it on the screen?

Comment: Okay, this is in response of someone who gave an answer and deleted it afterwords. The main theme of his answer was "why is Canvas object even part of DAO?". It is a good question and I should have been bit more clear on that part.

Actually what I am working on is a kind of a image manipulation application and the doodling/drawing would need to be persisted at some point, hence, Canvas IS needed to be part of DAO. There is also a Bitmap object in DAO, the question remains as to how would I pass it on to the View without mingling the code.

Comment: draw takes Canvas param, this Canvas can be created by new Canvas(Bitmap)

Comment: @pskink : so what you are saying is that the Canvas parameter to draw() is a ouput parameter, right? Whatever I draw on to it, it get's displayed on the screen?
What happens if I pass a pre-built Canvas object to the draw() function? does it get displayed as is on the screen?

Comment: what screen are you talking about? if you want the stuff to be drawn onto a Bitmap just pass new Canvas(Bitmap)

Comment: Okay, I think the confusion is between Canvas and Bitmap. As far as I have understood, Bitmap class holds the actual data of the image while Canvas is the "way" through which Bitmap data can be manipulated. Correct me, if I am wrong.

And by screen, I mean the "device Screen".